# Surface Book Wubi Ubuntu 18.04 - Failed with grub boot loader configuration

Tags: grub2, uefi, wubi, surface

I just used wubi to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Surface Book that uses UEFI. During the installation, it said grub failed to installed. Then after I restart, I can no longer log back into Windows. I'm now stuck with the grub console.

I've done some readings and tried to use boot-repair to troubleshoot. But the auto-repair did not work. Here's the link on the report, I hope some experts can shed some lights.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MBgNn5YZSS/

I have 1 harddrive with 3 partitions:

> C:\ -> Windows 10 (Bitlocker encrypted)
>
> D:\ -> Ubuntu (NTFS without encryption)
>
> (last) -> system recovery

Comment: I've attempted to install Ubuntu on a new partition rather than through Wubi by using a bootable USD drive. Towards the end of the installation step, I got the same failure message.


**GRUB installation failed**

The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

Answer (score 0):

I used a live ubuntu USD to boot up and installed Ubuntu onto a new partition (Non-windows partition).

And I received the Grub install failure error again.

I boot up the live ubuntu once again, installed boot-repair and perform an auto repair and I'm able to boot up to Windows now.